# Copy NSManagedObject into a temporary NSManagedObject in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have copied an `NSManagedObject` object into a temporary `NSManagedObject` object. So that I can use that temporary `NSManagedObject` object, if there is no change in the user input. Otherwise, I can use the actual `NSManagedObject` object.

The problem is, if I change any value in the actual `NSManagedObject` object, it automatically reflects in a temporary `NSManagedObject` object. When I searched on the net, they said `NSManagedObject` does not conform to `NSCopying` protocol. Also, copied object would have a reference to actual `NSManagedObject` object.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: How **exactly** are you copying one object to another one?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be helpful to know why you 'need' a temporary `NSManagedObject`.

Classes like `NSManagedObject` are of reference type.  That means both your original and temp object reference the same address in memory and changes to one will be reflected in the other.

However, structs are value type.  Maybe you can create a struct that you can initialize with your managed object and use that to store whatever data you need to hold temporarily.

Also, specific to `NSManagedObject`s, the idea is that they *are* temporary.  When you change properties on a managed object it's not persisted until you write it to the persistent store with the managed object context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, strictly saying, yes, there is. Just create in managed object context new object of that entity-type and copy all you properties into that newly created object one by one.

```
let objCopy = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:<#entityName#>, into:<#context#>)

objCopy.propertyA = objOrigin.propertyA
objCopy.propertyB = objOrigin.propertyB
...
```

But the very premise of coping managed object inside of the context is a bit obscure to me. NSManagedObject's are only reflect some temporary state of actual piece of data. So, if you need to reverse some changes done to the object, you can always do that. You can ask managed object context, what objects have changed, you can ask managed object about properties that have changed, you have `undo()` method, etc.

So, you should consider to review your application design. Pretty sure, you don't need to have temporary copy of you object.

In case, if your copies are not of temporary nature and should be saved into persistent store - you'll have to copy those object manually and property-wise (look the first part of my answer). In case of such coping there will be separate challenge to decide, what to do with references - copy referenced objects (deep copy), or just keep referencing to the same objects as the original